# How to get SAK from Mifare 1k on Android with QtNfc?

Tags: android, c++, qt, nfc

I'm developing an application for android, using Qt (QtNfc, qt version: 5.12.11), that has to read the uid and sak from any mifare card(1k, 4k, ultralight etc).  I get over with the target detected functions, receive the uid for the mifare but I cannot find how to retrieve the SAK from this card..

```
qDebug()<< "Target detected";
QByteArray cardUid = target->uid();
QUrl cardUrl = target->url();
if(target->type() ==  QNearFieldTarget::MifareTag){
    qDebug() << "Mifare tag";
}

for(int i=0;i < cardUid.size();i++){
    qDebug() << QString::number(cardUid.at(i)).toInt();
}'
```

I tried with QJniAndroid to call

```
#define NFCATECHNOLOGY  QStringLiteral("android.nfc.tech.NfcA")

void myfunction::nfcManager{
   QAndroidJniObject nfca = getAndroidTech(NFCATECHNOLOGY); 
   jshort sakS = nfca.callMethod<jshort>("getSak");
} 

QAndroidJniObject  nfcManager::getAndroidTech(const QString &tech)
{
   QString techClass(tech);
       techClass.replace(QLatin1Char('.'), QLatin1Char('/'));
       // Getting requested technology

       QAndroidJniObject ret = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("QtNfc","getStartIntent", "()Landroid/content/Intent;");
       QAndroidJniObject m_intent = ret;
       QAndroidJniObject extraTag = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/nfc/NfcAdapter", "EXTRA_TAG", "Ljava/lang/String;");
       QAndroidJniObject tag = m_intent.callObjectMethod("getParcelableExtra", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Parcelable;", extraTag.object<jstring>());

       Q_ASSERT_X(tag.isValid(), "getTagTechnology", "could not get Tag object");
       const QString sig = QString::fromUtf8("(Landroid/nfc/Tag;)L%1;");
       QAndroidJniObject tagTech = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(techClass.toUtf8().constData(), "get",
               sig.arg(techClass).toUtf8().constData(), tag.object<jobject>());
       return tagTech;
} 

But after this I get a lot of undefined references like: "undefined reference to `short QAndroidJniObject::callMethod<short>(char const*) const'" .. 

It's there any other way to get the sak from a mifare card readed with android phone?
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get ATQA(byte[]) and SAK, for your reference

```
Parcelable tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
if (tag != null) {
                byte[] id = ((Tag) tag).getId();
                NfcA picc = NfcA.get((Tag)tag);
                int sak=picc.getSak();//sak=08 for Mifare Classic 1KB
                byte[] atqa=picc.getAtqa();// Anticollision support check
```